# Same gesture for multiple actions in a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, gestures, swipe

Say we are have a TODO list app.

Our app has just one view for simplicity:
1. Left swipe shows menu on the right (similar to facebook chat on right)
2. Right swipe shows menu on the left (similar to facebook nav on the left).
3. A list of tasks on the main view, where a left swipe will activate delete/modify action for an item on the list.

Now there are two left swipes: (1). activates right menu, (3). Activates actions on an item.

This looks confusing to me, when a user will left swipe on the main view, what action should be taken?

Any suggestions to have features 1, 2 and 3 coexist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first left swipe (activates right menu) can be set to start from the edge of the screen. like the side menu in facebook.

The seocnd left swipe (Activates actions on an item) can be set to start from anywhere EXCEPT the edge of the screen. Just like when you're moving about a zoomed in page in a browser

Comment: Yeah, so the "swipe" gesture feels more like a "drag in from the edge"-feature.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a separate button or a press and hold to show the main menu? Are they two left swipes close to each other? If so, it might be easy for the user to trigger the wrong one. You have to remember that touch gestures need a very big margin of error.